# Scrapy: Defining XPaths with numbered Divs & Dynamically naming item fields

Tags: python, scrapy, items

I'm a newbie with regards to Scrapy and Python. Would appreciate some help here please...

I'm scraping a site that uses divs, and cant for the life of me work out why this isn't working. I can only get Field1 and Data1 to populate... the overall plan is to get 10 points for each page...

have a look at my spider - I can't get field2 or data2 to populate correctly...

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import AttorneysItem

class AttorneysSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "attorneys"
    allowed_domains = ["attorneys.co.za"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.attorneys.co.za/CompanyHomePage.asp?CompanyID=537",
        "http://www.attorneys.co.za/CompanyHomePage.asp?CompanyID=776",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div//div//div[3]//div[1]//div//div'):
            item = AttorneysItem()
            item['Field1'] = sel.xpath('//div//div//div[3]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]/text()').extract()
            item['Data1'] = sel.xpath('//div//div//div[3]//div[1]//div[1]//div[2]/text()').extract()
            item['Field2'] = sel.xpath('//div//div//div[3]//div[1]//div[2]//div[1]/text()').extract()
            item['Data2'] = sel.xpath('//div//div//div[3]//div[1]//div[2]//div[2]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

It s super frustrating. The link to the site is http://www.attorneys.co.za/CompanyHomePage.asp?CompanyID=537.

Thanks
Paddy

--------------UPDATE---------------------------

So I've gotten a bit futher, but hit a wall again.

I can now select the elements okay, but I somehow need to dynamically define the item fields... the best I've been able to do is the below, but it's not great because the number of fields is not consistent, and are not always in the same order. Essentially what I a saying is sometimes their website is listed as the third field down, sometimes it's the fifth.

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = AttorneysItem()
    item['a01Firm'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="name-h1"]/text()').extract()
    item['a01Field'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-3 display-label"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
    item['a01Data'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-9"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
    item['a02Field'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-3 display-label"]/text()').extract()[1].strip()
    item['a02Data'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-9"]/text()').extract()[1].strip()
    item['a03Field'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-3 display-label"]/text()').extract()[2].strip()
    item['a03Data'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-9"]/text()').extract()[2].strip()
    item['a04Field'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-3 display-label"]/text()').extract()[3].strip()
    item['a04Data'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-9"]/text()').extract()[3].strip()
```

Thanks again to any and all who can help :D

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the `xpath` you provide:

- You only need to use "//" in the beginning, the rest should be "/".
- Using only element name to extract is not clean. It leads to bad readability and possibly bad performance. One reason is that many, if not most, webpages contain levels of nested `div`s. Instead, make good use of [selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/selectors.html).

Besides, You don't need the for loop.

One cleaner way to do this is as follows:

```
item = AttorneysItem()
    item['Field1'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-3 display-label"]/text()').extract()[0]
    item['Data1'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-9"]/text()').extract()[0]
    item['Field2'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-3 display-label"]/text()').extract()[1]
    item['Data2'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-lg-9"]/text()').extract()[1]
    yield item
```

In case you don't know, you can use [scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/shell.html) to test your xpath.
Simply type `scrapy shell url` in command line, where url corresponds to the url you are scraping.

Comment: Thanks man - this is awesome! As I say, I'm a complete noob, so your help is much appreciated. I'll give it a try in a bit!

Comment: yup, no worries. I've been through this stage as well. let me know how it goes!